# ansible find: get path of a directory

Tags: ansible

In find I'm getting the following output, how to filter only the path?

```
find:
  paths: /jv01
  recurse: yes
  file_type: directory
  patterns: 'agent_13.3.0.0.0'
register: oem
- debug:
  var: oem

"oem": {
        "changed": false,
        "examined": 24156,
        "failed": false,
        "files": [
            {
                "atime": 1545128921.5473044,
                "ctime": 1545120358.3347161,
                "dev": 64768,
                "gid": 1027,
                "inode": 67,
                "isblk": false,
                "ischr": false,
                "isdir": true,
                "isfifo": false,
                "isgid": false,
                "islnk": false,
                "isreg": false,
                "issock": false,
                "isuid": false,
                "mode": "0755",
                "mtime": 1545120358.3347161,
                "nlink": 28,
                "path": "/jv01/oracle/agent_13.3.0.0.0",
                "rgrp": true,
                "roth": true,
                "rusr": true,
                "size": 4096,
                "uid": 1027,
                "wgrp": false,
                "woth": false,
                "wusr": true,
                "xgrp": true,
                "xoth": true,
                "xusr": true
            }
        ],
        "matched": 1,
        "msg": ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the paths by iterating over the list and pulling out each path individually.

You must do this because find returns a list of dicts about each file. There may be more than one returned, after all.

```
- name: Show file paths
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.path }}"
  with_items: "{{ oem.files }}"
```

Answer (score 5):

try Jinja2 filters

```
{{ oem.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}
```

be avare that this will create a list. If you dont want list you can use this

```
{{ oem.files | map(attribute='path') | join('') }}
```

but in case there are more files found, the output will be all paths of found files together.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled onto your post while trying to pry the contents of path from the results of find.  Figured I'd add my findings for any other beginners trying to figure this out.

Bear in mind, this is not an elegant solution but it helped me in understanding the data structure of the find results:

```
- name: "find directory xyz"
  find:
    paths: "{{ search_path }}"
    recurse: yes
    file_type: directory
    patterns: "xyz"
  register: find_matches

- name: "print the path of our first result"
  debug:
    var: find_matches.files[0].path
  when: find_matches is defined
```

Find's results are stored in a dictionary of lists of dictionaries.  You'd definitely want to iterate over the results in a real case scenario.